# variable specific distance matrices compatible with strings

Tags: r

I'm working on a project where I need to group cases together. I have data on npi's, with info on the npi's like address, phone and name.
My goal is to group the npi's which are most alike in the same group. I want to achieve this by first creating a distance matrix and than determine
a treshold from which to group cases together. However I'm encountering difficulties on how to create a distance matrix for string variables. 
I basically have two questions:

First, how to make a distance function for comparing similarities between cases in a dataframe creating a distance matrix as output?
The more values they share on the same variables, the closer I want them to be, so the higher/lower score on the distance matrix.

Second, how to make this distance function compatible with string variables?

code:

```
#sample data
df <- read.table(text='npi a  b  c
             51  6  2  1
             52  6  2  6
             53 10  9  2
             54  7  4  7
             55  7 10  5
             56  8  5  7
             57  7  2 10
             58  5  9  3
             59  8  4  6
             60  1 10  2', header=T, sep='')

#convert 1st column of data as the row index
df1 <- df[,-1]  
rownames(df1) <- df[,1]

#calculate distance
library('proxy')
dist_func <- function(x, y) length(intersect(x,y))/3 
proxy::dist(df1, method = dist_func)
```

output:

```
          51        52        53        54        55        56        57            58        59
   52 0.6666667                                                                                
   53 0.3333333 0.3333333                                                                      
   54 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000                                                            
   55 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.3333333 0.3333333                                                  
   56 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.3333333 0.6666667                                        
   57 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.6666667 0.3333333 0.6666667 0.3333333                              
   58 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.3333333 0.0000000 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.0000000                    
   59 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.0000000 0.3333333 0.0000000 0.3333333 0.0000000 0.0000000          
   60 0.6666667 0.3333333 0.6666667 0.0000000 0.3333333 0.0000000 0.6666667 0.0000000 0.0000000
```

Questions:
1. What is defined here as x and y? the rows in contrast to all other rows or something else?
 With this defined function the distance is not variable specific. I only want two cases to 'intersect' if the values appear on the same variable
2. What would I need to add to the function to make it variable specific?

Furthermore this method doens't seem to work on string variables.

code:

```
   #create dataset with strings 
   df2 <- read.table(text='npi dier  getal  mubilair
             51  "aap"  een  tafel
             52  vis  twee stoel
             53 paard  twee  zetel
             54  kip  drie  fouton
             55  beer vier   fouton
             56  aap  vijf   bureau
             57  tijger  zes bank
             58  zebra  zeven  sofa
             59  olifant  acht  wastafel
             60  mens acht  spiegel', header=T, sep='')
   #convert 1st column of data as the row index
   dfstring <- df2[,-1]
   rownames(dfstring) <- df[,1]
   #calculate distance
   library('proxy')
   dist_func <- function(x, y) length(intersect(x,y))/3 
   proxy::dist(dfstring, method = dist_func)
```

Output:

```
             51        52        53        54        55        56        57        58        59
   52 0.0000000                                                                                
   53 0.0000000 0.6666667                                                                      
   54 0.6666667 0.0000000 0.0000000                                                            
   55 0.3333333 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.6666667                                                  
   56 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.3333333                                        
   57 1.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.3333333                              
   58 0.0000000 0.6666667 0.6666667 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000                    
   59 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.3333333          
   60 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.0000000 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.6666667
```

This distance matrix makes no sense
The problem is with the intersect command:

```
   > dfstring[1,]
      dier getal mubilair
   51  aap   een    tafel
   > dfstring[2,]
      dier getal mubilair
   52  vis  twee    stoel
   > dfstring[4,]
      dier getal mubilair
   54  kip  drie   fouton
   > intersect(dfstring[1,], dfstring[2,])
   data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows
   > intersect(dfstring[1,], dfstring[4,])
      dier
   54  kip
```

Is there a function like intersect which works with string variables as well?

So, how to make my initial function variable specific and how to make it compatible with string variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For `x` and `y`, think "row x" compared with "row y". It may be informative to change your function to be

   ```
   dist_func <- function(x, y) {
     browser()
     length(intersect(x,y))/3
   }
   ```

   and then run it, looking at the actual values of `x` and `y` on the first call to your function. (You probably won't need to go beyond the first and second instantiation of your function.)
2. `intersect` does not know anything about position within the vector, it is solely set-based, meaning "presence of". The [help page](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sets.html) is even titled "Sets" and starts with

   ```
   Performs *set* union, intersection, ...
   ```

   To get what you want, aren't you just looking for plain equality?

   ```
   dist_func <- function(x, y) sum(x == y)/3
   ```

   NB: true equality can be problematic if looking at numeric (non-integer) numbers, per [R FAQ 7.31](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f).
3. Your data is plagued with `factor`s, not `character`s. You might notice

   ```
   str(df2)
   # 'data.frame': 10 obs. of  4 variables:
   #  $ npi     : int  51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60
   #  $ dier    : Factor w/ 9 levels "aap","beer","kip",..: 1 8 6 3 2 1 7 9 5 4
   #  $ getal   : Factor w/ 8 levels "acht","drie",..: 3 4 4 2 5 6 7 8 1 1
   #  $ mubilair: Factor w/ 9 levels "bank","bureau",..: 7 6 9 3 3 2 1 4 8 5
   ```

   Notice, for example, that the first value in `$getal` is `"acht"`, which is an integer 3 internally within the factors. You'll notice that the fourth integer-values for the three columns are 3, 2, 3 (respectively, which matches   the distance metric of `0.667` in column "51" and row "54".

   Either use `read.table(..., stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` or change your distance function to be something like:

   ```
   dist_func2 <- function(x, y) {
     if (is.factor(x)) x <- as.character(x)
     if (is.factor(y)) y <- as.character(y)
     sum(x == y)/3
   }
   ```

   (I suggest `stringsAsFactors` personally, but YMMV.)